# Asp.net Regular Expression validator for textbox

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am using the Regular Expression validator to validate the Text input in my webpage. The Regular Expression which i am using is

```
 ValidationExpression="([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[.]|[;]|[:]|[@]|[']|[&quot;]|[(]|[)]|[/])+"
```

My problem is,  I cant able to enter the text input like this **\\Arun\\**. I need to enter forward slash in the textbox. Is anyone know the validation expression to enter the slash, please post the details .Thanks

Comment: Use `"^[-a-zA-Z0-9 _.;:@'&quot;()/\\]+$`

Comment: Thanks Ulugbek Umirov

Comment: I solved my issue to include the "\\" in the Validation Expression. ValidationExpression="([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[.]|[;]|[:]|[@]|[']|[&quot;]|[(]|[)]|[/]|[\\\])+"

Comment: Why do you use `[a-z]|[A-Z]` while you can use `[a-zA-Z]` (I combined all of them for you in my sample).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to validate against, but it looks like you just want to validate against an empty Textbox. If so just use the

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator />
```

instead of a regex validator.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my issue to include the "\\" in the texbox by adding "\\" in the Validation Expression.

```
ValidationExpression="([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[.]|[;]|[:]|[@]|[']|[&quot;]|[(]|[)]|[/]|[\\])+"
```